# "Вглубь ночи" — где ударение, какой падеж?

Tags: орфоэпия, падежи

Вглубь ночИ или вглубь нОчи, как правильно? В каком падеже слово ночь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Викисловаре (https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C) добавлен местный падеж: в ночИ. Но это не относится к Вашему случаю. У Вас Р. п.: вглубь (чего?) нОчи. Это современное произношение. Как было раньше и допустимо ли изменение ударения в современной поэзии — эти вопросы оставляю без ответа.

Answer (score 5):

Правильно: **вглубь (чего?) нОчи.**

Предлог ВГЛУБЬ управляет Р.п.

Существительное ***ночь*** относится к акцентному классу Е: **ударение в ед. числе только на основе,** а во мн. числе оно переходит на окончание (кроме И.п и В.п).

**Примечание**

Как уже сказано, есть еще форма в **ночИ** (местный падеж, вариант предложного падежа).

Также ударение может **переходить на предлог**: зА ночь, нА ночь, дО ночи и до нОчи.